# I try to create a code for me to create an embed, but all the options are required when I make the order, how can I do so that they are not required

Tags: python, discord

Here is my code

```
@bot.command(name="embed", description="Use this command to create a embed")
async def embed(ctx, *,title, content, urlthumbnail, urlimage, footer, fieldname, value):
    if not isOwner(ctx):
        return await ctx.respond("Only owners or staff can use this command.")

    ctx.respond
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{title}", description=f"{content}")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{urlthumbnail}")
    embed.set_image(url=f"{urlimage}")
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{footer}")
    embed.add_field(name=f"{fieldname}", value=f"{value}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    embed=discord.Embed(title=" <:pnlstore:1028979693241761833> | Embed Created ", description=f"<:oui:1030175858431885396> Embed created by **{ctx.author.mention}**")
    embed.set_footer(text=".gg/pnlstore")
    await ctx.respond(embed=embed)
```

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in title

Comment: assign default values to variables (or assign `None` or empty string). ie. `embed(..., title="Hello World", ...)`. If you assign `None` or empty string then you can also use `if/else` to skip code when you don't get any value.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: you have to only assign some default values in `async def embed(ctx, *, title="default title", content="default content", urlthumbnail="default URL with image", urlimage="default URL with image", footer="default footer", fieldname="default fieldname", value="default value"):`

Comment: or you can use `None` as default value `async def embed(ctx, *, title=None, content=None, urlthumbnail=None, urlimage=None, footer=None, fieldname=None, value=None):` and later use `if/else` like `if footer is not None: embed.set_footer(text=footer)`

Comment: frankly, default values should be described in every tutorial about functions in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, default values should be described in every tutorial about functions in Python

You have to assign default value to make it optional

ie.

```
async def embed(ctx, *, title="default title", content="default content", urlthumbnail="default URL with image", urlimage="default URL with image", footer="default footer", fieldname="default fieldname", value="default value"):
```

Common method is to use `None` as default value and later use `if/else` to skip element if it is `None`

```
async def embed(ctx, *, title=None, content=None, urlthumbnail=None, urlimage=None, footer=None, fieldname=None, value=None): 

    #if footer is not None: 
    if footer: # shorter, and it skips code also when string is empty
        embed.set_footer(text=footer)

    if not title:
        return await ctx.respond("It needs title")

    if description:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=content)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=title)

    if urlthumbnail:
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=urlthumbnail)

    if urlimage:
        embed.set_image(url=urlimage)

    if footer:
        embed.set_footer(text=footer)

    if fieldname and value:
        embed.add_field(name=fieldname, value=value)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    # ... code ...
```